# How do i set default item in DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a DataGridViewComboBoxCell in a datagridview.I'm loading values in it at form_load.It shows blank in DataGridViewComboBoxCell initially,when new row is added.But my problem is how do i set Default value, say "Others" in that DataGridViewComboBoxCell.So that whenever i try to add new row it will show default item in it.

I would like to show my code to you.

DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboItem_current = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

```
                comboItem_current.Items.Clear();
                comboItem_current.Items.Add("Other");

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds_Item.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboItem1 = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;  
                    comboItem1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());

                }
```

please help out....thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an ancient post, but hopefully, I can help some people avoid my confusion.

Using CellFormatting is a loser because it calls it every time anything touches the cell.  The result is that the value gets set back to the default constantly.

What worked for me was handling the DefaultValuesNeeded event like so:

```
private void OnGridDefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["Position"].Value = PositionEnum.Any;
}
```

This allowed me to set the default value, and lets the user change the value.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, using CellFormatting event makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this way: [Set DatagridviewComboBoxColumn Default Value](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/ba5c5d12-7eed-4b61-80b9-a576d5ee95be/)

**OR** this way:

Just add `CellFormatting` event for datagridview

```
void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) //Index of your DataGridViewComboBoxColumn 
    {
        e.Value = "Default Value";
    }
}
```

Comment: @varshatavade It's my pleasure..If it solved your question..you can accept the answer by clicking the checkbox (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79780/improve-the-indication-to-askers-that-they-can-accept-answers-to-questions/79793#79793)..

Comment: See Jamies answer, using CellFormatting event makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

Why not keep it simple and just use something like

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MyProp}" Width="*" Header="MyHeader" ></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Of course your DataGrid needs DataContext property set with IEnumerable where MyObj have MyProp

Comment: This is not WPF, its about WinForms