# Selecting value in combobox contained with a datagridview control?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to populate and select a VB.net combobox control contained within a datagrid called dgrid_SongList (already defined).  Here's my code:

```
Dim dgvcc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
dgvcc = dgrid_SongList.Rows(dgrid_SongList.RowCount - 1).Cells(3)
dgvcc.Items.Add("1")
dgvcc.Items.Add("2")
dgvcc.Items.Add("3")
```

Whilst this works I can't work out how to automatically select the first value.  Within a normal combobox control I can but not when it's within a datagrid.

Any pointers ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055312/how-do-i-set-default-item-in-datagridviewcomboboxcell

Answer (score 1):

Add this ..

```
Dim CCol as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(dgrid_SongList.Columns(3), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

dgvcc.Value = CCol.Items(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for that however I get an error when I add the above code.  It's "syntax error in cast component.  two arguments separated by comma are required".

Comment: Hmm, we're getting closer but it's still throwing an error message: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
".  This is within a loop so the same section of code is run each time a row is added.  Could this be a problem, do I need to redim dgvcc or something ?  I'm completely baffled by this ....

Comment: @PhilipLee : might be my mistake .. in your dgv column .. it's changed from 0 to 3 .. try again !